# How can this question be more clear to reopen?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I asked this question: [What are the available Signals in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73789240)

It immediately closed, claiming it was not clear enough. I edited (added the package name) the question to ask for a reopen, now I have 2 reopen votes but did not get 1 more reopen vote unfortunately.

Is it really unclear? If yes, how can I ask more clear question to get an answer?

Comment: As far as I can see, it's still in the reopen queue awaiting more reviews. If you want to expedite that process, one way to do so is to review a bunch of questions yourself, which makes the queue move faster, since you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: The question seems clear enough to me, searching for "[sun.misc.Signal(signalStr)](https://www.google.com/search?q=sun.misc.signal(signalstr))" turns up some advice:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/19711062/3648282 - also, in general, you wouldn't want to use the integer values; you'd want to use the include file, *hiding* the values from the code (making it portable, to Oracle OS). --- Not difficult to answer, from what you asked; but you are at the mercy of the Review Queue. :)

Comment: Thank you @ErikA I did not know/remember that there is a reopen-vote queue. I just checked it now and see the message: "This queue has been cleared!". I was waiting for like 10 days and I thought that my questions is just forgotten and no one will never check it again. Are you sure that it was waiting on the queue? Maybe SO can add something like "Your question is enqueued to reopen votes review queue" note.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for your advices, I am aware of the sun packages problems and searched for the alternatives but the client was requesting custom-signal-handling even they know the JVM issues.

Comment: @IsmailYavuz I currently see 638 items in the reopen queue under https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats, if you see it as cleared you likely either have a filter on, or are currently suspended from reviewing. Under https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73789240/timeline, you can see the timeline for the question, including _Added to review_ indicating the question entered the queue, and the _Reopen votes_ item which indicates it left the queue. The UI tends to not emphasize if a question is in a review queue for closing/reopening/triage/etc.

Comment: @Ismail, the second hit for that search returns code useful for what you mention in your above comment: https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Signal.java - my point here is not to answer your other question, but to mention, with respects to this one, that the detail appears sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @ErikA I will check that from now on!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I don't see why this question would be closed as "unclear".  The question is very clear and it describes something very explicit.

As a Java developer, my reaction would be to reach for the downvote button because "wtf, languages don't have signals, only operating systems do, and oh yeah Microsoft only has like three signals whereas Unix has like 15 or more", but that wouldn't warrant its closure.

Comment: Some searching implies that this is a Sun internal API that is not intended to be used by programmers. It seems to have something to do with representing OS signals internally in order to control the operation of the JVM.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: This is where the 'wtf" comes in.  I was taught ages ago in an operating systems course that it's the OS that owns the signals, and not the programs.  I have no doubts that the internal APIs in Java leverage this (and have more implementations depending on where they're actually run on) to do Stuff™, but I as a Java developer have never had any appetite to want to inspect or enumerate them.  In shell scripts to trap signals, sure, but that's a different language and different domain altogether.